# MediaElement.MediaEnded() not firing from ViewModel?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, mvvm, windows-10

I have two MediaElements created in my ViewModel and bound in my View. On MediaOne.MediaEnded(), I'm trying to fire another method. BUT, MediaEnded() never fires!

Here is the relevant code:

**ViewModel:**

```
    private MediaElement _mediaOne;

    public MediaElement MediaOne
    {
        get { return _mediaOne; }
        set { _mediaOne = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private MediaElement _mediaTwo;

    public MediaElement MediaTwo
    {
        get { return _mediaTwo; }
        set { _mediaTwo = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public SpeechViewModel()
    {

        _mediaOne = new MediaElement();
        _mediaTwo = new MediaElement();

        MediaOne.MediaEnded += MediaOne_MediaEnded;
        MediaTwo.MediaEnded += MediaTwo_MediaEnded;
    }

        private async void MediaOne_MediaEnded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
        private async void MediaTwo_MediaEnded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do other stuff
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding mediaOne}"/>
<ContentControl Content="{Binding mediaTwo}"/>
```

Comment: From your code, I did not see you specify any media source, can you show the code how you specify the media source?

Comment: Thanks for the reply -- actually, my problem was that I am binding to "mediaOne" and "mediaTwo" when I should be binding to "MediaOne" and "MediaTwo"...heh. Thanks!